# /etc/crypttab not working

Tags: 10.04, encryption

I used the Disk Utility to create an encrypted volume on an external drive.  When I click the Unlock Volume button in that program, it mounts the drive for me.

Now, I want to automate this process so that it will happen at boot-up.

When I run `sudo cryptsetup luksUUID /dev/sdb1`, I get this:
`ca709269-1e3e-4e9e-9e08-7248f0e6c5a6`

So, I create `/etc/crypttab` like this:
`backup_drive UUID=ca709269-1e3e-4e9e-9e08-7248f0e6c5a6 none`

And I added this line to `/etc/fstab`:
`/dev/mapper/backup_drive /mnt/backup ext3 default 0 2`

When I reboot, Ubuntu tells me that the device is not available to map, so I tell it to skip it.  It appears that the `/etc/crypttab` is not getting run correctly.

How can I debug this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you need a fourth parameter there to specify the encryption type.

This is what my `/etc/crypttab` looks like:

```
home_crypt /dev/disk/by-uuid/6f13e221-69f0-4f0e-9082-e2e7b32fc1dd /mnt/Keys/home-data luks
swap_crypt /dev/sda3 /dev/urandom swap
```

The [Crypttab manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man5/crypttab.5.html) says that all four fields are mandatory.

To test your settings, you can use the following commands to start and stop the cryptdisks after you make your changes.

```
cryptdisks_start
cryptdisks_stop
```

Comment: Thanks, I misunderstood the man page.  Also, I like the use of /dev/disk/by-uuid -- that's easy to understand.

Comment: FYI for future travelers, the fourth parameter is no longer mandatory

Answer (score 5):

The format for the `/etc/crypttab` file is:

`encrypteddiskname  UUID=xxxxxxxxxxxx   /etc/keyfilename`

To get the UUID of the disk you need to run: `blkid /dev/sdb1`

Do not use the `blkid` of the `/dev/mapper/encrypteddiskname`.